# How to make a C program execute continuously while accepting input from stdin?

Tags: c

The following is an excerpt from myprogram.c:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   UserOptions opt;
   DmtxEncode *enc;
   unsigned char codeBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
   int codeBufferSize;
   opt = GetDefaultOptions();


   /* Read input data into buffer */
   codeBufferSize = ReadInputData(codeBuffer, &opt);

   //do something with the input data

   exit(0);
}

static size_t ReadInputData(unsigned char *codeBuffer, UserOptions *opt)
{
   int fd;
   ssize_t bytesRead;
   size_t bytesReadTotal;

   /* Open file or stdin for reading */
   fd = (opt->inputPath == NULL) ? 0 : open(opt->inputPath, O_RDONLY);

   /* Read input contents into buffer */
   for(bytesReadTotal = 0;; bytesReadTotal += bytesRead) {
      bytesRead = read(fd, codeBuffer + bytesReadTotal, BUFFER_SIZE);
      if(bytesRead == 0)
         break;
   }

   return bytesReadTotal;
}
```

This takes the input in the form of `echo 1234 | myprogram` and the program generates an output and terminates.

I would like to make this program execute continuously and accept user inputs where two separate inputs are differentiated by a newline (`\n`) character. Say for example I would like to give `1234 \n 5678 \n 6363 \n` as the input. The program should first take the input `1234`, generate an output for it, then see that there is a newline and treat `5678` as the second input, generate an output and so on.

I have tried modifying the `ReadInputData` function as follows:

```
static size_t ReadInputData(unsigned char *codeBuffer, UserOptions *opt) {
    int fd;
    ssize_t bytesRead;
    size_t bytesReadTotal;
    size_t startOfBlock;
    unsigned char tmpBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    /* Open file or stdin for reading */
    fd = (opt->inputPath == NULL) ? 0 : open(opt->inputPath, O_RDONLY);

    for (bytesReadTotal = 0;; bytesReadTotal += bytesRead) {

        startOfBlock = tmpBuffer + bytesReadTotal;
        bytesRead = read(fd, startOfBlock, BUFFER_SIZE);

        for (int i = startOfBlock; i < startOfBlock + bytesRead; i++) {
            if (tmpBuffer[i] != '\n')
                codeBuffer[i] = tmpBuffer[i];
            else
                break;
    }
    }


    return bytesReadTotal;
}
```

and enclosed the workings of the `main` within a `while(1)` loop but this just produces the output for a single input and terminates the program.

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong here?

EDIT: According to the suggestions, I modified the `ReadInputData` function as follows:

```
static size_t
ReadInputData(unsigned char *codeBuffer, UserOptions *opt) {
    int fd;
    ssize_t bytesRead;
    size_t bytesReadTotal;
    unsigned char* startOfBlock;
    unsigned char tmpBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    /* Open file or stdin for reading */
    fd = (opt->inputPath == NULL) ? 0 : open(opt->inputPath, O_RDONLY);

    for (bytesReadTotal = 0;; bytesReadTotal += bytesRead) {

        startOfBlock = tmpBuffer + bytesReadTotal;
        bytesRead = read(fd, startOfBlock, DMTXWRITE_BUFFER_SIZE);

        if (bytesRead == 0)
            break;
        if (bytesRead == -1)
            FatalError(EX_IOERR, _("Message read error"));
        else if (bytesReadTotal > DMTXWRITE_BUFFER_SIZE)
            FatalError(EX_DATAERR, _("Message to be encoded is too large"));

        for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++) {
            if (startOfBlock[i] != '\n')
                codeBuffer[i] = startOfBlock[i];
            else
                break;
        }

    }
```

This solves the problem of newline characters but the program exits after taking one input instead of accepting continuous inputs. The contents of `main` are inside a `while(1)` loop.

EDIT: 
`main` with while loop. No `exit(0)` present in `main`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   UserOptions opt;
   DmtxEncode *enc;
   unsigned char codeBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
   int codeBufferSize;
   opt = GetDefaultOptions();

   while(1){

   /* Read input data into buffer */
   codeBufferSize = ReadInputData(codeBuffer, &opt);

   //do something with the input data

   }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure you can read `\n` as part of the input. Normally it is an input terminator. You can let your program loop, reading input after each action.

Comment: It would also be a good idea to assign a file descriptor to `fd`.

Comment: You most likely read 4k (or at least BUFFER_SIZE, or at least as much as is available) data (i.e., all of it), encounter the first newline and then throw 3.99k away upon return. Btw, if you are indeed reading text input I strongly recommend (f)scanf or fgets. Reading strings or numbers with scanf skips any whitespace including newlines which frees you from the fiddling with low-level input (and makes the program more tolerant towards the input format).

Comment: @Paul of course they can read '\n'; it's a common source of error, actually.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, can you please elaborate a bit on what you mean by ¨let your program loop, reading input after each action.¨

Comment: @Paul and `fd = (opt->inputPath == NULL) ? 0 : open(opt->inputPath, O_RDONLY);` does assign a file descriptor, quite elegantly, although it is never checked (but since input is read from stdin anyway, there is no path name issue here).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, Iĺl keep in my the point about scanf/fgets. But at the moment I am trying to understand how I should modify the `ReadInputData` function to make the input separated by a newline and at the same time not terminate the program.

Comment: `do { ... } while(!feof(fp))`

Comment: @JL2210 There is no `fp` ;-). You'll have to check the return value of `read()` for 0.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, I see...He didn't assign in his second version.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, yes, you can read `\n`, but you need a next function call to read the next line. That is what I mean with "input terminator".

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, youŕe right. That was a typing error. I edited the question. 
A concrete answer would be very helpful.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, if I check `read()` return value for 0, it only indicates the EOF. But I want the input to be separated by `\n`.

Comment: Why not simply read the input line by line with `fgets`?

Comment: @interjay because I would like to read binary data as well and I suppose `fgets` is not suitable for that purpose.

Comment: `fgets` works just fine with binary data if it's delimited by `\n` (which you say in your question). Though delimiting binary data with newlines is somewhat strange and limiting because the data itself won't be able to hold `\n` characters.

Comment: regarding: `opt = GetDefaultOptions();`   The variable `opt` is not defined as a pointer and that is ALL that can get assigned to `opt` in this manner.  Also, this seems to be a `java` function, not a `c` function

Comment: When asking a question about a run-time problem, as this question is doing, please post a [mcve] so we can duplicate the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: regarding `for (bytesReadTotal = 0;; bytesReadTotal += bytesRead) {`  strongly suggest using the results of the call to `read()` as the conditional in a `while()` loop to control the reading

Comment: regarding: `bytesRead = read(fd, startOfBlock, BUFFER_SIZE);`   The second parameter should point to where the read bytes are placed.  However, `startOfBlock` is declared a `size_t`, not a pointer

Comment: I think you need to show your `main` function with the `while(1)` loop because, if your `exit(0)` is inside it, that'll be the problem. NB You don't need to call `exit` from `main`, just return the value you want.

Comment: Perhaps you want to step back and reconsider your choice of IO APIs. `<stdio.h>` exists for a reason. You might just as well use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a lot of problems with the code in `ReadInputData`. The biggest one is that your input is not preserved between calls. `read` will get all the data available to it (up to the count you pass in). So if there happens to be two lines available, `ReadInputData` will get both of them into `tmpBuffer`. You save the first one and the second is discarded when `tmpBuffer` goes out of scope.

You need a buffer that is preserved across calls.

Another problem is this test:

```
else if (bytesReadTotal > DMTXWRITE_BUFFER_SIZE)
```

if `DMTXWRITE_BUFFER_SIZE` is quite small such that the first two lines added together are greater than this, there will be a fatal error. I'm pretty sure you really need something like:

```
if (bytesReadTotal == BUFFER_SIZE)
{
    FatalError(EX_DATAERR, _("Message to be encoded is too large"));
}
bytesRead = read(fd, startOfBlock, min(DMTXWRITE_BUFFER_SIZE BUFFER_SIZE, BUFFER_SIZE - bytesReadTotal));
```

i.e. you need to be sure there is space in the buffer *before* you do the read. Also, there's no point in reading more than you are allowed to.

---

Returning to the first problem, there are two ways you can solve this.

1. Make `tmpBuffer` and `bytesReadTotal` static variables
2. Put them in a `struct` and pass a pointer to it into the call

```
struct ReadBuffer
{
    char tmpBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    size_t bytesReadTotal;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct ReadBuffer buffer;
    buffer.bytesReadTotal = 0;

    // stuff 

    codeBufferSize = ReadInputData(codeBuffer, &opt, &buffer);

    // stuff

}

static size_t ReadInputData(unsigned char *codeBuffer, UserOptions *opt, struct ReadBuffer *buffer)
{
    // stuff

    startOfBlock = buffer.tmpBuffer + buffer.bytesReadTotal;
    // and so on
}
```

Then you need to add in all your code to manage the buffer and so on, but such a thing already exists in the C library, it's called a `FILE`. If you used the standard library buffered `FILE` API instead of raw Unix system calls, your life will be much easier. There's even a function (that many in comments are telling you to use, which reads and returns input up to the next `\n`. It's called [fgets()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).

---

Just spotted another problem. You open the file each time you call `ReadInputData`. It's not a problem for `stdin` because you just use file descriptor 0. However, for any other file, you'll just read the first line each time until your process runs out of file descriptors. In my solution above, you'd have to open the file in `main` and add the file descriptor to the `ReadBuffer` struct. If you do that, you are definitely reinventing the C library `FILE`.

Here's a rough reimplementation

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   UserOptions opt;
   DmtxEncode *enc;
   unsigned char codeBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
   ssize_t codeBufferSize;
   opt = GetDefaultOptions();

   FILE* input = opt->inputPath == NULL ? stdin : open(opt->inputPath, "r");
   if (input == NULL)
   {
       // Handle the error
   } 

   while(1)
   {

       /* Read input data into buffer */
       codeBufferSize = fgets(codeBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, input);
       if (codeBufferSize == -1)
       {
           // Handfle IO error
       }
       else if (codeBufferSize == 0) 
       { 
           // reached end of file
       }
       else if (codeBuffer[codeBufferSize - 1] != '\n')
       {
           // Handle input truncated because line was too long
       }
       else 
       { 
           //do something with the input dat
       }
   }
   if (input != NULL)  
   {
       fclose(input);
   }
}
```